# Enabling 'on the fly' CRS transformation via python console of QGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-2.18, qgis-python-console

I am using QGIS 2.18.

Is there a way to enable the 'on the fly' transformation project setting from the python console?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Specify destination CRS. 4326: PostgisCrsId for WGS84
CRS = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId)

render = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
render.setDestinationCrs(CRS) # Set Destination CRS
render.setProjectionsEnabled(True) # Enable OTF
```